# Settings key unreadable on target SDK 32

Tags: android, security, sdk, settings, android-12

after migrating the codebase to android 12 target SDK 32, i am trying to get the value of the below settings key

> bluetooth_name

but on pixel devices on android 12 i keep getting this crash

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.SecurityException: Settings key: <bluetooth_name> is only readable to apps with targetSdkVersion lower than or equal to: 31
```

from what i've tried so far, there is no extra permission that is needed for this change, also it works completely fine on almost any other device

am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

There are new restrictions on Android 12, and Bluetooth requires some [extra permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions)

However, I don't think that it's a permissions issue -- you simply can't access that setting with Android 12 or higher. You'll need to use the [BluetoothAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter) class to get the info you need:

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String name = adapter.getName()
```